# Userscripts error in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, userscripts

I'm not working with userscripts at the moment, I just noticed the following error when checking the Network tab for the page I'm working on to see what it's doing (It's taking forever to serve my GET request).

`Uncaught ReferenceError: unsafeWindow is not defined`
`chrome-extensions://bpcnnanbbiobnpfamcdpkopledhphmh/fbex.js:864`

Can anyone tell me what this is?

Thanks!

Comment: fbex. Sounds like someone wrote a Facebook extension which failed. Remove that extension, because the page's global `window` object is not directly available. For this reason, any script which relies on it will not work correctly.

Comment: I did install an extension yesterday that looked like it was supposed to get feeds from different sites I input. Removed it now. Write an answer and I'll give you rep :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the Extension `Hear Youtube`. It doesn't appear to have any adverse effect on other websites.